# Prevent FlexSlider thumbnails from changing main image on scroll on mobile

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I am trying to get flexslider to only change the main image if a thumbnail is clicked on mobile. Right now what's happening is that if you scroll the thumbnails, the main image changes too. You can see the sample here. https://dev.time2visit.com/hotel/destination_package_view/116

Any help is much appreciated.

```
<div id="slider" class="flexslider">
                        <ul class="slides">
                            <li>
                                <img src="<?= base_url("/uploads/feature_image/{$hotel->feature_image}") ?>" alt="Image Alternative text" title="" class="hotel_property_feature_img">
                            </li>
                            <?php foreach ($hotel->images as $image) : ?>
                                <li>
                                    <img src="<?= base_url("/uploads/images/{$image}") ?>" alt="Image Alternative text" title="Outside Crowne Plaza">
                                </li>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
                        <ul class="slides">
                            <li>
                                <img src="<?= base_url("/uploads/feature_image/{$hotel->feature_image}") ?>" alt="Image Alternative text" title="" class="hotel_property_feature_img">
                            </li>
                            <?php foreach ($hotel->images as $image) : ?>
                                <li>
                                    <img src="<?= base_url("/uploads/images/{$image}") ?>" alt="Image Alternative text" title="Outside Crowne Plaza">
                                </li>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Below is the JS

```
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
    // The slider being synced must be initialized first
    $('#carousel').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: false,
        slideshow: false,
        itemWidth: 210,
        itemMargin: 5,
        asNavFor: '#slider'
    });
    $('#slider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: false,
        slideshow: false,
        sync: "#carousel"
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you add a working example? Right now it's hard to give advice because we can't see your code/how it is currently working.

Comment: @justDan https://dev.time2visit.com/hotel/destination_package_view/116. Visit this page and view the slider in mobile. You will see how if you scroll the thumbs, the main image changes.